# How to call several (static) Java-methods in a row in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, call, static-methods

So far I found two ways to call static methods from Java as functions in Clojure.

```
;; using .
(. Math min 12 13)
;; using /
(Math/min 12 13)
```

The calls can become more complicated when using return-values of one call, for the next call.

```
(. (. System out) println "Static call from Clojure.")
```

It seems to not work using the "/" notation:

```
((System/out) /println "Static call from Clojure.")
```

Probably the "."-notation is meant to handle this kind of method-calls. In my opinion the "."-notation becomes difficult to read even when there are only two method calls in a row.

Is there a clearer way to call methods in a row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you aware of this notation?

```
 (.. System (getProperties) (get "os.name"))
```

Notice the two dots.

Which will expand to:

```
(. (. System (getProperties)) (get "os.name"))
```

[Java Interop](http://clojure.org/java_interop) on Clojure.org.

Answer (score 1):

Try following.

```
(-> (System/out) (.println "Static call from Clojure."))
```